# Como relacionar os valores de uma lista ao nome do dataframe em R

Tags: r, loop

Eu estou trabalhando com 90 dataframes diferentes, mas que vão todos passar por uma edição semelhante. Para isso, estou tentando trabalhar com loops para que eu não precise repetir quase 100 linhas de código 90 vezes.

Depois de importar todos os bancos, eu criei uma lista com os nomes deles (vou usar um recorte da lista como ilustração):

```
datas <- ls(pattern = "final_")
datas

[1] "final_36CalcScore" "final_36DairyForm" "final_48CalcScore" "final_48DairyForm"
```

Agora, eu preciso usar o nome dessas variáveis dentro de um loop para as edições do banco, como por exemplo, remover a primeira linha e depois separar as colunas do banco.

Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
for (k in datas) {
  assign(k, k[-1,])
}
```

Porém eu recebo o erro "incorrect number of dimensions".
Então eu tentei um comando head(k) dentro do loop para verificar se estava lendo corretamente, mas não retorna nada, então acredito que o programa não está entendendo que o valor da lista é o dataframe.

Alguém sabe me dizer se faz sentido isso que estou tentando?

Answer (score 2):

`datas` é um vetor com os *nomes* dos data.frames; `k` é uma string de texto, não o objeto. Use `get` para pegar o objeto com aquele nome:

```
for (k in datas) {
  assign(k, get(k)[-1,])
}
```